# What could be causing this interference, and how can it be resolved?

Tags: networking, router, proxy, ethernet

I have two wired connections going into my desktop, from two different ISPs. Connection 1 is a symmetric gigabit fiber connection directly to the computer, and Connection 2 is coaxial, passed through a modem and a router. I have used [Go Dispatch Proxy](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/go-dispatch-proxy) to set up two local proxy servers, so that I can (for instance) run a speed test on Connection 1 in Edge and Connection 2 in Firefox (as well as using the connections simultaneously for two different tasks, which is the use case).

Each of the Ethernet connections has a different controller: Intel (1 Gbps) for the port that Connection 1 is using and Aquantia (10 Gbps) for the port that Connection 2 is using. However, when I run two speed tests at the same time, I do not get the same results.

| Condition | Connection 1 (Mbps) | Connection 2 (Mbps) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 only | 920/940 | N/A |
| 2 only | N/A | 1400/45 |
| 1 and 2 | 308/942 | 1230/45 |

It almost seems as if the two Ethernet ports are sharing bandwidth, but this does not make any sense to me. There are two different ISPs, two different wiring systems (coaxial versus fiber), two different controllers in the desktop, two different proxies (one for each connection), and two different browsers for testing. The desktop certainly has enough cores and RAM that neither of these should be a bottleneck.

What is causing this apparent interference between the two connections, and how might I resolve it?

Comment: 920/940 what? Apples? Bytes? milliseconds?

Comment: Apples per millisecond

Comment: Sure they may be sharing bandwidth. At these speed levels, your PC’s PCIe topology comes into play. Your CPU supports finite PCIe bandwidth, which may be further reduced by the motherboard.

Comment: @DanielB - Just the one port is 10 Gbps, though, so even if they shared bandwidth, there should be more than enough, since the motherboard should be set up to handle that much. Also, although I did not mention this in the question, I was able to get about 2.1 Gbps download a while back using load balancing through Go Dispatch Proxy and the same two connections (even though I have not been able to replicate it). So I do not think that is it.

Comment: Are you running the speed test against different servers?

Comment: @user1686 - Yes, they are two different servers.